# Найти количество сущностей на последний день месяца

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет!

Что изначально имеется.

1. Есть таблица Метод эксплуатации(method_exploit), в котором хранится список определённых
   способов эксплуатации:

| Id | title | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Метод 1 | method1 |
| 2 | Метод 2 | method2 |
| 3 | Метод 3 | method3 |
| 4 | Метод 4 | method4 |
| 5 | Метод 5 | method5 |
| 6 | Метод 6 | method6 |
| 7 | Метод 7 | method7 |

2. Также ещё есть и таблица Журнал эксплуатации(journal), которая имеет следующий вид:

| Id | entity_id | date | method_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-09-28 12:00:00 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-09-28 13:10:00 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-09-30 14:10:00 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-09-24 14:10:00 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-09-25 15:10:00 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 2021-09-27 15:10:00 | 7 |
| 7 | 3 | 2021-09-28 15:10:00 | 1 |

то есть в этой таблице у нас находится журнал, в котором отмечается какой метод эксплуатации(method_id) был у той
или иной сущности с идентификатором entity_id, начиная с определённого момента(date).

3. Что мне нужно:

я сейчас пишу хранимую функцию, которая на входа принимает 1 параметр:

- дату, то есть ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ДЕНЬ определённого месяца;

мне нужно найти КОЛИЧЕСТВО СУЩНОСТЕЙ, у которых на ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ДЕНЬ определённого месяца переданного
в качестве параметра значение способа эксплуатации равно 1 или 2. То есть method_id = 1 или method_id = 2.

В приведённом выше примере НА ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ДЕНЬ СЕНТЯБРЯ количество таких сущностей будет равняться 2. Это сущности
с entity_id = 1 и entity_id = 3. Так как у entity_id = 1 последнее значение метода эксплуатации за дату '2021-09-30 14:10:00'
то есть самую последнюю дату для этой сущности в сентябре равно 2. У entity_id = 3 последнее значение метода эксплуатации
за дату '2021-09-28 15:10:00' то есть самую последнюю дату для этой сущности в сентябре равно 1.  А вот у entity_id = 2
последнее значение метода эксплуатации за дату '2021-09-25 15:10:00' то есть самую последнюю дату для этой сущности в сентябре равно 3,
поэтому сущность с entity_id = 2 не подходит под условие.

В итоге количество сущностей, удовлетворяющих условию поиска = 2. Как мне построить SQL запрос в PostgreSQL, чтобы в запросе посчитать
количество таких сущностей?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8150 - вот тут я накидал демо-данные. Может кто-нибудь помочь сформулировать запрос?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
  j.entity_id, 
  to_char(MAX(j.date), 'MONTH YYYY') as last_date,
  (
    SELECT t1.method_id
    FROM journal t1
    WHERE j.entity_id = t1.entity_id AND MAX(j.date) = t1.date
  ) as last_method_id
FROM journal j
WHERE TO_CHAR(j.date, 'MONTH YYYY') = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2021-09-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MONTH YYYY')
GROUP BY j.entity_id
HAVING (
    SELECT t1.method_id
    FROM journal t1
    WHERE j.entity_id = t1.entity_id AND MAX(j.date) = t1.date
  ) IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, Женя! Помогло!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT MAX(date), entity_id 
  FROM journal j
  WHERE j.method_id IN (1,2) AND TO_CHAR(j.date, 'MONTH YYYY') = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2021-09-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MONTH YYYY')
  GROUP BY entity_id 
  HAVING MAX(date) = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM journal as t1 WHERE t1.entity_id = j.entity_id AND TO_CHAR(t1.date, 'MONTH YYYY') = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2021-09-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MONTH YYYY'))
) t;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогло!